# adding layers in ggplot2 with for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I guess this is easy, but I do not get it. It relates to the use of for loops on ggplots.
The question is: why do these two codes here below give different results? It looks as if on the code with the loop, only the second iteration is taken into account, but I do not know why.
The underlying question would be: is it possible to run such loops with ggplot2 objects?
Thanks a lot for your help,
David

```
# Code 1

aux <- 3:4
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

for (i in 1:2)
 
p <-  p + geom_segment(aes(x = aux[i], y = 0, xend = aux[i], yend = 35), colour = "purple")


# Code 2

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = aux[1], y = 0, xend = aux[1], yend = 35), colour = "purple")

p <- p + geom_segment(aes(x = aux[2], y = 0, xend = aux[2], yend = 35), colour = "purple")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot` does a bit of lazy evaluation, so in your `for` loop example `i` isn't evaluated immediately. If we look at the layers, we can see the `i` is still there as `i`, not as `3` and `4` in the respective iterations. When you print the plot, that is when `i` is evaluated--at whatever value it takes when you print the plot. When can even change `i` after the loop to cause problems:

```
aux <- 3:4
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

for (i in 1:2) {
  p <-  p + geom_segment(aes(x = aux[i], y = 0, xend = aux[i], yend = 35), colour = "purple")
}
  
p$layers
# [[1]]
# geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
# stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
# position_identity 
# 
# [[2]]
# mapping: x = ~aux[i], y = 0, xend = ~aux[i], yend = 35 
# geom_segment: arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, lineend = butt, linejoin = round, na.rm = FALSE
# stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
# position_identity 
# 
# [[3]]
# mapping: x = ~aux[i], y = 0, xend = ~aux[i], yend = 35 
# geom_segment: arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, lineend = butt, linejoin = round, na.rm = FALSE
# stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
# position_identity 

## changing `i` later can still cause problems:
i = 5
print(p)
# Warning messages:
# 1: Removed 32 rows containing missing values (geom_segment). 
# 2: Removed 32 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

So, no, you can't really use `for` loops quite like that. There are probably workarounds, but this feels like an XY problem - this isn't how `ggplot` is intended to be used, so using it this way will be difficult.

It's hard to know what your real use case is, but in this case we could put `aux` data in a data frame and do it like this (ggplot is made to work with data frames):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(
    data = data.frame(aux),
    aes(x = aux, xend = aux),
    y = 0, yend = 35, colour = "purple"
  )
```

Though, for the the special case of vertical lines, we can use `geom_vline` with the `aux` vector directly:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = aux, colour = "purple")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gregor. Using aux as a data.frame will do it just fine .I had not even think about it, thanks a lot. My real data is a little bit more complex than the one I posted, so that I need to use segments, and not vlines. Thanks again,

Comment: Will do. Was not aware. Thanks. Best.